# Node/Express I can't get the header set up in my route

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, request, response-headers

I have a backend that uses Node and the Express framework and a frontend in React. The code is in Typescript.

My backend uses the elastic search client to fetch the data but I don't think that's where my problem lies.

I need to retrieve a parameter that I fetch from the backend via the http header of my response in my frontend.

To do this I used these two functions from the Express doc http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set and http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json

So I wrote the following code for my route:

```
searchRouter.get('/search', (asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const response = await client.search<HitResult>({
    index: my-index,
    scroll: "1m",
    body: {
      My elastic request
    }
  });
  res.set('data_to_send',response.body.data_to_send);

  console.log('is there a hearder? ', res.headersSent) //always return false
  
  res.json(response);
})));
```

But the header does not change with this method. So I tried to create an asynchronous function to fill my header with the following code:

```
async function buildHeader(response: express.Response<any, Record<string, any>>, headerName: string, headerValue: string | undefined): Promise<any> {
  response.header(headerName,headerValue);
}

searchRouter.get('/search', (asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const response = await client.search<HitResult>({
    index: my-index,
    scroll: "1m",
    body: {
      My elastic request
    }
  });
  await buildHeader(res, 'data_to_send', response.body.data_to_send);

  console.log('is there a hearder? ', res.headersSent) //always return false

  res.json(response);
})));
```

Whatever I do the header does not change and keeps its basic form, the following one:

```
content-length: "50643"
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong and could help me, that would save me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the node process listen to port 80 directly or is it served via a web server? Some web server configurations could strip non-standard headers.. BTW, I believe `buildHeader` doesn't need to be an async function.

Comment: You're right about the buildHeader, making it asynchronous is pretty useless here. My server listens on port 9000 and it sends the data to my frontend on port 3000 and I use the following middleware: `app.use(cors(corsOption));` with `const corsOption={ origin:'http://localhost:3000', credentials: true, optionSuccessStatus:200 }`. So by looking at https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html I think what I need to do is to add the exposedHeaders configuration option.

Comment: did using `exposedHeaders` work?

Comment: Yes, that was the solution, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Find myself pretty stupid for not having thought of it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Itai pointed out to me, my problem came from the middleware I was using, CORS. By adding in the options of this middleware the two following fields:

```
'allowedHeaders': ['data_to_send'],
'exposedHeaders': ['data_to_send'],
```

Everything works as expected.
For more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers